# SOLR 4.1 Language Detection

Tags: solr, multilingual, apache-tika

I'm trying to use [`LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) that comes with SOLR to detect languages when indexing documents. It looks pretty straightforward implementation, i have put following to solrconfig.xml

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
  <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="langid.fl">title</str>
    <str name="langid.langField">language_s</str>
    <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>
    <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>
    <bool name="langid.map.individual">true</bool>
    <str name="langid.map.individual.fl">title</str>
    <str name="langid.whitelist">en, fr, de, it, ar, ja, zh-cn, zh-tw</str>
    <bool name="langid.map.keepOrig">true</bool>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

but when i start solr it says cannot load class `LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory`. I had also tried `TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory` but no luck. I probably missing something. Do I need any additional package/library/classes to have multi language detection functionality in SOLR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have the `apache-solr-langid-X.X.jar` and the dependant jars in `contrib/langid/lib` available for solr.